# version updation in node.js in ubuntu12

Tags: node.js, ubuntu

Am trying to update my current node version to latest.

my current node version

```
udmin@WS1A079:~$ node -v
v0.6.12
```

so i tried following commands for updating

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js
```

after that i used

```
   sudo apt-get update
```

It outputs following ......

```
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release.gpg
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release                                                                  
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release.gpg                                                         
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com precise Release.gpg                                                         
Hit http://dl.google.com stable/main amd64 Packages                                                      
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release                                                             
Hit http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org dist Release.gpg                                                 
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security Release.gpg                                              
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com precise Release                                                             
Hit http://dl.google.com stable/main i386 Packages                                                       
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main TranslationIndex                                                    
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Sources                                                        
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main Sources  

    Reading package lists... Done
    W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable/main amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/dl.google.com_linux_chrome_deb_dists_stable_main_binary-amd64_Packages)
    W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable/main i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/dl.google.com_linux_chrome_deb_dists_stable_main_binary-i386_Packages)
    W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
```

i again run `sudo apt-get update` it again outputs the same abow message

How can i solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nodejs -y
```

Answer (score 0):

If you installed Node from apt-get, try `sudo apt-get upgrade` instead. Update updates the repository contents in your cache, not the installed programs. If you did not it won't help.

Comment: As for the duplicate source issue, check out http://askubuntu.com/questions/183007/how-to-fix-duplicate-sources-list-entry-warning but its not really the reason why it won't update Node.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to upgrade Node to the latest stable or any version. You can also install directly from nodejs.org and don't have to use the command line. Run the following:

```
sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n stable
```

Package "n" denotes a node helper and it will upgrade to the latest stable version. You can also specify the version as below.

```
sudo n 0.10.32
```

Once completed, you can check the version installed using

```
node --version
```